# g cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, visual-studio-code, java.util.scanner

g cannot be resolved to a variable is the error popping up. I've initialised g in the for loop, so why this error ? I'm a beginner, so can anybody explain in as many simple and understandable words as possible.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bellman {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Enter the number of nodes");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Enter the cost matrix");
    
    for (int j = 0; j<n; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k<n; k++) {
            int g[j][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
    
    

}
}
```

g cannot be resolved to a variable. I've initialised g in the for loop, so why this error ?

Comment: No: you haven't created `g` yet. Presumably `g` is supposed to be a two dimensional int array, but you have no code anywhere that declares it as such before you start using it.

Comment: What exactly do you think `int g[j][j]` does?

Comment: int g[j][j] = sc.nextInt(). Isn't this declaring and initialising both ? I did the same thing for n before this. I directly declared and initialised n in int n = sc.nextInt(); @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: It's supposed to be int g[j][k] sorry. @tgdavies

Comment: No, it does not. Clearly your `g` is a 2d int array, so even if this worked (which is doesn't =) it's definitely not an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is most likely what you want to achieve:

```java
        int g[][] = new int[n][n];

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                g[j][k] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
```

You have to initialize the array with a specific size, only then you can assign values at a given indexes.

Comment: int g[j][j] = sc.nextInt(). Isn't this declaring and initialising both in the for loop ? Is there any way to initialise with size directly in the for loop. I did the same thing for n before this. I directly declared and initialised n in int n = sc.nextInt();

Comment: it's not declaring, it is only assigning. you can declare a variable in the loop for sure, but it's scope is only within the loop, you cannot use is outside. and you cannot declare a specific index of the array, you need to whole array, which does not make sense to declare inside the loop